# Excel 2016 How to make a cell editable , enter text on it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

I am using Excel 2016 and i am quite new to this. I have a dropdown list in cell `B18` that contain some values, and under it i have a cell `B19` that is related to that cell `B18`. In the `B19` cell i have this formula :

```
=IF(B18="International Incoming MT – Business ","Money Transfers",IF(B18="International Outgoing MT – Business ",  "Money Transfers",IF(B18="Annual Account Maintenance Fee – Business ",   "Account Maintainance",IF(B18="GPRS POS Fee ",   "POS",IF(B18="E-Banking Maintenance Fee ",   "Business E-Banking",IF(B18="Inactive POS Fee ",   "POS",IF(B18="Debit Card Issuance Fee ", "Debit Card",IF(B18="E-Tax Payment ",        "Transaction E-Banking",IF(B18="Incoming Money Transfer ",      "Money Transfer",IF(B18="Outgoing Money Transfer – Normal ",       "Money Transfer",IF(B18="E-Banking Money Transfer Dom. – Business ",      "Money Transfer - E-Banking",IF(B18="E-Banking IOMT –Business ",   "Money Transfer - E-Banking",IF(B18="","",IF(B18="Other","",""))))))))))))))
```

So when user selects ''Other'' option in dropdownlist `B18` cell , the `B19` cell should become blank and allow him to enter text on it , to type something on it , but in this case it doesn't allow to type on it , it just stays blank ,and not be able to write on it

Comment: You need a VBA macro for this.

Comment: Replace all them nested `IF`s with a `vlookup` to a hidden sheet. Don't use the same cell for user input and a formula, rather have an option in your dropdown for manual input and then have your sheet work off `B20` instead of `B19` if the user selects that option. (Well have an intermediate cell that chooses between these two and then have all the other references to `B19` in your sheet point to that intermediate cell). You can use VBA to lock or unlock `B19` and `B20` to make it more clear.

Comment: I dont know VBA , im only using formula , and the logic is If user selects the  'OTHER' option from the dropdownlist , it should enable the B19 cell (as a textbox) to allow me write on it

Comment: You can't do that with a formula

Comment: you can have another cell in which the user can put editable text then refer to that cell if the drop down has `Other`.  But you cannot have a formula in a cell you want to allow user input.  The user input would overwrite the formula.